# DataContractJsonSerializer - deserializing to non-attributed/inherited class

Tags: c#, json, attributes, datacontractserializer, json-deserialization

I would like to use the c# DataContractJsonSerializer to de-serialize some json into a type that lacks serialization attributes. This type also inherits from multiple interfaces with each interface having many public properties.

I cannot alter the type I am trying to de-serialize to, nor the interfaces from which it inherits - is what I'm trying to do possible in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is what I'm trying to do possible in c#?

All you have to do is writing a small piece of code to test.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CL1));
var m = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{""I1"":""test1"",""I2"":""test2""}"));
var cl1 = ser.ReadObject(m) as CL1; 
Console.WriteLine(cl1.I1 + " " + cl1.I2);
```

So the answer is **YES**

```
public interface II1
{
    string I1 { set; get; }
}
public interface II2
{
    string I2 { set; get; }
}
public class CL1 : II1, II2
{
    public string I1 { set; get; }
    public string I2 { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have written similar working code. I am currently assuming the problem in my instance (after further inspection) is that the that type does not have a default constructor.

Comment: @fusi Better, use Json.Net, If it doesn't do it by default, there are many ways to hook into deserialization process.